# Pyrocms controle panel not accessing

Tags: php, pyrocms

I have uploaded my pyrocms site info on FileZilla and my database is uploaded on CPanel.
All things are going right but when I open CP (Controle Panel) of pyrocms then I got this security message:

> No direct script access allowed

please any one help me to get out from this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That message is loaded if you try to go to /controllers/admin.php or something similar. Is that what you are doing? Because that would be silly.

Go to `http://example.com/installer` to install it, then click "Control Panel" to go to `http://example.com/admin` after that.